# Defining a variable inside a function

Tags: python, function, undefined

I am having some trouble with my code it keeps saying

```
NameError: name 'km' is not defined
```

I define this in the function.
Would it be better if I used the choice function to do this?

```
def userinput():
    while True:
        try:
            km = int(input("Enter the amount of kilometres you need (1 or 2)"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print ("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
    return
userinput()
if km >= 3:
    userinput()
if km <= 0:
    userinput()
if km == 1: 
    zone = 0.01862
if km == 2:
    zone = 0.02
```

Comment: variables are only visible within the scope in which they are first declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
def userinput():
    while True:
        try:
            km = int(input("Enter the amount of kilometres you need (1 or 2)"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print ("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
    return km

km = userinput()
if km >= 3:
    km = userinput()
if km <= 0:
    km = userinput()
if km == 1: 
    zone = 0.01862
if km == 2:
    zone = 0.02
```

The reason to that is as Alnitak said -

> variables are only visible within the scope in which they are first declared

Hopefully this will help you, Yahli.